# Passing the ID of clicked link to PHP code without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to pass the ID of a clicked link to PHP code without reloading the page.

Currently, I am using the following code to pass the ID in the href attribute in the tag:

```
<?php
    $sql="select * from category";
    $execute=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($execute)){ ?> 
            <li><a href="index.php?did=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="javascript:show()"><?php echo $row['category'] ; ?></a></li>
<?php 
    } 
?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="waxing" style="display:none">
        <h2 id="cat_price" style="color:#f5c658">Price Category Waxing</h2>
        <ul class="ul1">
<?php 
    function sub() {
        if(isset($_GET['did']))
        {
            $id=$_GET['did'];
            $sql="select * from midcat where cid=$id";
            $execute=mysql_query($sql);
            if(mysql_num_rows($execute)>0){
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($execute)){ 
                ?>
                    <li><a href="#" id="wax_normal" ><?php echo $row['midcat']; ?> </a></li>
                <?php 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sub();
?>
```

Is it possible to do the same thing without reloading the page?

Comment: you can save it in a variable and check ,is empty or not.

Comment: To not reload page, you use `AJAX`. I find jQuery AJAX particularly easy to use/implement.

Comment: I can't argue for jQuery specifically, but yes, Ajax is *the* tool you need to do this.

Comment: Move the whole `function sub()` business to a new page and use ajax to access that new page to populate the new `<li>` list. Also don't use `mysql_` especially how you are using it (injecting right into the sql statement)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned, you will want to use `AJAX` to fetch your other list. I will demonstrate and notate. I am using jQuery because I am familiar with it and I find it easy to use. Traditional javascript AJAX will work just as well:

**page1.php (whatever this page is called)**

Add jQuery libraries in the `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Change this line, it doesn't need to be a link, I like to use the `data` attribute:

```
<li data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['category'] ; ?></li>
```

On this same page add the ajax:

```
<script>
// When the page finishes loading
$(document).ready(function() {
    // When the user clicks any <li>, activate script
    $("li").click(function() {
        // Assign the value of the data attribute
        var thisBtn =   $(this).data('id');
        // If an <li> doesn't have this attribute, stop
        if(thisBtn == undefined)
            return false;
        // Start the ajax
        $.ajax({
                // Where to send request
                url: 'ajax.index.php',
                // What to send
                data: { did: thisBtn },
                // How to send
                type: 'post',
                // What to do when request succeeds
                success: function(response) {
                    // Save the contents of the response into
                    // whatever has the id="list"
                    $("#list").html(response);
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Place a drop spot where you want your list to show up on this page:

```
<!-- this is where ajax will drop the list on your page -->
<span id="list"></span>
```

Create a new page and put the `<ul>`, function, execution of function on this new page

**ajax.index.php**

```
<?php
function sub()
    {
        // In the ajax, I told it to use $_POST, so change to
        // post instead of get
        if(isset($_POST['did'])) {
            $id=$_POST['did'];
            // Don't do this anymore.............vvv
            $sql="select * from midcat where cid=$id";
            // Don't use mysql_ anymore
            $execute=mysql_query($sql);
            if(mysql_num_rows($execute)>0){
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($execute)){ 
                ?>
                    <li><a href="#" id="wax_normal" ><?php echo $row['midcat']; ?> </a></li>
                <?php 
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
<ul class="ul1">
<?php sub().PHP_EOL; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to refresh page you have to use AJAX:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

on your javascript onclick event pass your id and replace href attribute value with a hashtag. like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:show(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)"><?php echo $row['category'] ; ?></a>
```

Now send an ajax request in show function. and use the response.